Correct Hydra Syntax for Brute-Forcing my ip camera website Login Pages Using Burp Suite?
I'm attempting to use Hydra to brute-force my Dahua ip camera website Login Pages by sending a POST request to 192.168.0.10/RPC2_Login, which I have captured via Burp Suite. However, Hydra seems to be missing the correct password even though it's in the pass.txt file and skips over it during its attempts.
Here's the POST request from Burp Suite I'm working with:
POST /RPC2_Login HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.10
Content-Length: 216
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.6367.118 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://192.168.0.10
Referer: http://192.168.0.10/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: WebClientSessionID=VZi8UTZca312147e2735871102
Connection: close

{"method":"global.login","params":{"userName":"admin","password":"EE319D4D7ED14B8F4B6DB6011B4DAC1B","clientType":"Web3.0","loginType":"Direct","authorityType":"Default"},"id":4,"session":"VZi8UTZca312147e2735871102"}


This is the Hydra command I used:
kali@kali:~/Desktop$  hydra -l admin -P pass.txt 192.168.0.10 http-form-post "/RPC_Login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:INVALID LOGIN"
Hydra v9.6dev (c) 2023 by van Hauser/THC & David Maciejak - Please do not use in military or secret service organizations, or for illegal purposes (this is non-binding, these *** ignore laws and ethics anyway).

Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) starting at 2024-05-13 19:12:59
[DATA] max 16 tasks per 1 server, overall 16 tasks, 1000 login tries (l:1/p:1000), ~63 tries per task
[DATA] attacking http-post-form://192.168.0.10:80/RPC_Login:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^:INVALID LOGIN
1 of 1 target completed, 0 valid password found
Hydra (https://github.com/vanhauser-thc/thc-hydra) finished at 2024-05-13 19:13:20
kali@kali:~/Desktop$ 


Could someone suggest the correct syntax for the Hydra command to effectively brute-force the login with the above JSON payload? What might be causing Hydra to skip the valid password?
Hydra seems to be unable to identify the correct password stored in the "pass.txt" file. It is bypassing the valid password during its execution!

Why is this releated to RTSP? Seems wrong

Thanks @Christoph, Simulating a brute-force attack on my Dahua IP camera login page using Hydra to understand its security strength

OK but you attack the cameras Webserver and not the rtsp Server. When want to attack the rtsp server you need rtsp:// uri.

Yes, brute-forcing RTSP is straightforward with the following command:
hydra -l user -P passlist.txt rtsp://192.168.0.1
However, I am referring to brute-forcing the web interface of a CCTV IP camera. See the command syntax:
"/:user=^USER&pass=^PASS^:H=Authorization: Basic dT1w:H=Cookie: sessid=aaaa:h=X-User: ^USER^:H=User-Agent: wget"
How should I write my Hydra syntax based on the my Burp Suite information result?
